# Is there a way to lock my skills?

Tags: diablo-iii

Due to some... overly enthusiastic mouse-clicking, I have now accidentally removed a skill from my bindings in the middle of combat several times.

Is there a way to lock my selection in to prevent me from accidentally click-dragging the skills of my action bar?

Comment: Wait what? Why are you ever clicking on your skills from your action bar? Use the hotkeys like a real human being.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I wasn't clicking on the skills to *use* them!  I was accidentally clicking on them to target a mob too close to the bottom of my screen.  Of course I use the hot keys!

Comment: Yep, happens to me, too. Can be really annoying.

Comment: @Jonas glad I'm not the only one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disabling elective mode should disable you from moving them off.

Comment: And blizzard has recently announced that they're working on a lock for elective mode too!

Comment: As an important note, disabling elective mode does *not* force your skills to return to the proper category.  If you want a build with multiple skills from a category: enable elective mode, set your skills, disable elective mode.  All skills set will stay set and there won't be any issue with dragging off the action bar