# Is it possible to lock the action bar?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to lock my skills?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67089/is-there-a-way-to-lock-my-skills)

Sometimes when I am running or walking around a lot I drag a skill off my action bar. Placing the skill back removes my Nephalem Valor.

Is it possible to lock the action bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you uncheck elective mode in Gameplay Options, the action bar will once again be locked.